# retrieve and set NTFS permissions using c#

Tags: c#, ntfs

I m confused how can I retrieve and set the NTFS permission for a directory using c#

such as Save `file Stream` and save `file security`

I'm looking for how can I save those properties for an executable so that it's stream cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the place to start.

See the example on that page using [`File.GetAccessControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e1fc3b8.aspx) method to get an instance.

NB.

> it's stream cannot be modified .

ACLs can always be overridden (not least my anyone with the Take Ownership privilege: as all local administrators have). If you want to ensure an exe is not modified you would be better looking at code signing.